# Wordpress custom thankyou page by order total

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I want to echo a custom message for each order total value in thankyou.php

example:

I tried this:

```
<?php $order->get_total();
    if ($order == '59.9') {
        echo 'custom 1';
    }
    else if ($order == '159.8') {
    echo 'custom 2';
    }
    ?>
```

May I know why it doesn't work?

Comment: If you wrote that something not work then describe what is expected behavior and what is actual behavior

Comment: It doesn't work because you failed to perform basic debugging, like checking what the value of `$order` actually is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the result of $order->get_total() to a variable and then check that variable in your if-else. Hopefully it's something like this:

```
<?php 
$mytotalorder = $order->get_total();
if ($mytotalorder == '59.9') {
    echo 'custom 1';
}
else if ($mytotalorder == '159.8') {
    echo 'custom 2';
}
?>
```

Hope this helps.